# android regular expression to match an address

Tags: android, regex, expression, match

In my android app i have to make a control on a edit text that contains an address,

for now my control is:

```
Indirizzo.toString().matches("[\\sa-zA-Z0-9]*")
```

But I must also add other characters to control,

such as: `\  .  n  °  ,`

How can I change the regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using something like so: `[\sa-zA-Z0-9\\\.n°/]*`.

That being said, that particular regular expression will also match an *empty* field. If you do not want this, simply replace the `*` (matches 0 or more repetitions of) with `+` (matches one or more repetitions of).

The `\` is a special character, which needs to be escaped, hence the extra `\` infront of it. The `.` is also a special character which also needs to be escaped.

So, in Java, you would need to use something like so: `[\\sa-zA-Z0-9\\\\\.n°/]*`

Comment: Thank you very much,
a 'last thing:

if I wanted to insert the character /

for example: via emilia, n ° 3/2

Answer (score 0):

You can make the regex accept all ASCII characters by using the following character class:

```
[\x00-\x7F]
```

Or, if you'd like to match those specific characters only, that is `\ . n ° ,`, simply add them to the character class:

```
[\\sa-zA-Z0-9\.n°,]*
```

Also, you should use `+` rather than `*` to eliminate zero-char matches.